# applying simple function to data

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Hi I try to apply simple function to data to create `sub_id` for groups.

```
test = data.frame(gr=gl(2,4), id =rep(c("Good","bad","ugly","dirty"),2),
                        count=c(175,1,13,11, 10,165,10,2))  


> test
  gr    id count
1  1  Good   175
2  1   bad     1
3  1  ugly    13
4  1 dirty    11
5  2  Good    10
6  2   bad   165
7  2  ugly    10
8  2 dirty     2
```

the condition for `sub_id` is like this

if group number is equal to minimum `count` with when `id==bad`, those groups sub_id is `red flag` else (other groups that do not satisfies this condition) `green flag`.

So I wrote this function

```
  sub_id <- function(gr,count,id){
    if (gr==min(count)&id=="bad"){
      "red flag"

    }
    else
    "green flag"  
  }
```

and tried

```
library(dplyr)

  test%>%
    group_by(gr)%>%
    mutate(color=sub_id(gr,count,id))
```

gives me

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   gr [2]
      gr     id count      color
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>      <chr>
1      1   Good   175 green flag
2      1    bad     1 green flag
3      1   ugly    13 green flag
4      1  dirty    11 green flag
5      2   Good    10 green flag
6      2    bad   165 green flag
7      2   ugly    10 green flag
8      2  dirty     2 green flag
Warning messages:
1: In if (gr == min(count) & id == "Bad") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (gr == min(count) & id == "Bad") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

the expected output

```
      gr     id count      color
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>      <chr>
1      1   Good   175   red flag
2      1    bad     1   red flag
3      1   ugly    13   red flag
4      1  dirty    11   red flag
5      2   Good    10 green flag
6      2    bad   165 green flag
7      2   ugly    10 green flag
8      2  dirty     2 green flag
```

Comment: can you explain your condition a bit better. what if the second row count was equal to 2? Then row 5 to 8 would be flagged as red?

Comment: Also R is case sensitve. In your `id` variable `bad` is in lower case and in your `if` condition it is with capital b `Bad`

Comment: @Masoud it is so simple. I just care about if group number is equal to minimum `count` with when `id==bad`. then as we grouped the data a group that satisfies this condition is `red flag` else `green flag`

Comment: @JilberUrbina Oh sorry I corrected that!

Comment: *minimum `count` with when `id==bad`* this is not clear to me. you want the minimum of `count` for those rows with `id==bad`? so let's say if we had a row with `id==bad` and `count==0` then everything would be flagged as green?

Comment: @Masoud yes exactly. I just care about gr == min(count) with id==bad. For beginning this data set is enough for me to work on my real data.

Comment: Why do all entries with `gr=1` get `"red flag"`ged? Why not just the row where `id="bad"`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers in my real data that number is dynamic. It is not always `1`. It could be any number.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Why do you mark *all* entries within a group with `"red flag"`? Why not just the row where `id=="bad"` and `gr==count`? Can you elaborate on the logic?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I would like to label the entire group as red flag because that group satisfies the ifelse condition.

Comment: @MauritsEvers as we can see the `gr 1` is clearly satisfying the condition but I cannot label whole group with `red flag`. That is my problem.

Comment: @Alexander I've added a solution below using `case_when`. There's no need for a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following reproduces your expected output.

```
test %>%
    group_by(gr) %>%
    mutate(colour = case_when(
        any(id == "bad" & gr == pmin(count)) ~ "red flag",
        TRUE ~ "green flag"
    ))
## A tibble: 8 x 4
## Groups:   gr [2]
#  gr    id    count colour
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <chr>
#1 1     Good   175. red flag
#2 1     bad      1. red flag
#3 1     ugly    13. red flag
#4 1     dirty   11. red flag
#5 2     Good    10. green flag
#6 2     bad    165. green flag
#7 2     ugly    10. green flag
#8 2     dirty    2. green flag
```

Explanation: We group by `gr`, then use `case_when` to flag *all entries* within the group with `"red flag"` if anywhere within the group `id == "bad"` and `gr == min(count)`.

Note that we need to use vectorised `pmin` (instead of scalar `min`).

---

### Update

With a user-defined function:

```
sub_id <- function(gr, count, id) {
    ifelse(any(gr == pmin(count) & id == "bad"), "red flag", "green flag")
}
test %>%
    group_by(gr) %>%
    mutate(colour = sub_id(gr, count, id))
```

Comment: That would be real easy like what you did or with `ifelse` but OP stated that wants the solution with a user-defined function. Cheers.

Comment: @Maurits Evers Thank you very much for your solution. It would be helpful to use user defined function as I may or anyone else wants to put other conditions. I find out that `any` function is missing in my user defined function. and it solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Masoud It *is* as easy; just wrap the whole thing in a function. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Alexander You're very welcome. I've added an update to address your comment; please take a look.

Comment: No problem at all. It is a simple question. Just was pointing out what OP has been seeking.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks, I just don't get it why we need `pmin` and just checked example in R help 
 `min(5:1, pi) #-> one number`
 `pmin(5:1, pi) #->  5  numbers`
why we need `pmin` for `count` ?

Comment: @Alexander You need *vectorised* `pmin` instead of *scalar* `min`. Just go through the conditions step-by-step for the first group: `pmin(gr == count)` returns `c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)`; `id == "bad"` returns `c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)`; vectorised logical AND of both conditions gives `c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)`, `any` then returns an overall `TRUE`. Does that clear things up?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Wow! absulately understood! Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: @Alexander No problem at all. Glad it cleared things up:-)